# Why is the result of my int multiplication wrong?

Tags: java, integer, integer-arithmetic

I have the the following code where the results exceeds the limit an integer  type variable can store and need to understand why I am getting this result (268,435,456=2^28)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int x = 16+256;
for( int i =0; i<6; i++) {
            x*=16;
        }
        System.out.println(x);
}
}
```

Comment: When I run the code I get 2^28=268,435,456

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider how this looks with all the values expressed in binary.

Initially, `x = 00000000000000000000000100010000`.  Then every time you multiply by 16, you add 4 zeroes to the right, and remove 4 digits from the left.

So you get results like

```
00000000000000000001000100000000
00000000000000010001000000000000
```

and so on.  But once you've done this 6 times, the first `1` disappears off the left end of the number - this is the integer overflow.  So you're left with

```
00010000000000000000000000000000
```

which is 2 to the 28.